# What is the best way to handle some hidden sites in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Web newbie.  I'm setting up a family website for sharing photos, etc.  I plan to purchase my own domain name and will rent space on some hosting platform.  I'm thinking ahead and will eventually want to create two more websites (another family website for my father's side of the family and a personal one for me).  The frugal side of me would like to limit the number of domains and hosts I have to purchase/rent.

I want the family websites to be hidden as much as possible (no SEO and requiring a login just to get to the main page), but I want my personal website to be public.

So far, what I've read says the above is difficult or cumbersome to do with wordpress multisite.  If this is true, then is it safe to assume separate wordpress installs are more appropriate?  Or, should I consider a new/different domain for my personal website?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this because it's not an actual programming question, and is looking for opinions - which is off-topic for SO. That said, Multisite would do exactly what you want it to do - you can use one domain with sub-directories or sub-domains to serve each site. WP even has an entire walk-thru to create a multisite: https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/

Comment: I'm not sure I agree this is an opinion.  I don't know how to handle this situation (I'm new to web development) and I can't find an answer on the web, so I'm asking.  I admit I am assuming there are right and wrong ways to handle this.  Maybe you know more and already "know" there's no pat answer.  If so, then  I think the proper thing to do is explain why (note some examples).  Otherwise, I learn nothing.  Would it help if I removed the "best" word from the question?

Comment: You might have a point about this question not being appropriate because it's not "software".  Having said that, I chose this site because I think web development is a sw thing and I saw lots of web development questions here.  For the sake of completeness, I noticed a stackexchange wordpress site, but I felt  this question could span both web development and wordpress (after seeing the first answer, I am now sure of it).

Comment: The first answer is an opinion...hence "I would...." This site is specifically for CODE related issues, not necessarily giving you advice on what options to choose for your development. WordPress exchange is probably a better place for this, although, those questions also are generally about code related issues. This isn't about software vs web development - stack overflow is for web development questions - but again, you are asking for options for setup, not a code based problem.

Comment: Even your first comment _Thanks, but could you explain why the multiple independent websites are the way to go?_ - Because it's an opinion. There is no singular way to do what you are asking. That said, good luck with whatever way you choose. WP is fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

- Buy one domain example.com
- Buy one hosting (shared or VPS if you have the skills)
- Create multiple independent Wordpress, and use subdomain site1.example.com, site2.example.com
- protect some websites with Htaccess (some free plugin may also do the trick, but with htaccess you are sure Crawler (like Google) won't access it.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain why the multiple independent websites are the way to go?  (It's not that I don't believe you, it's just that I'm trying to learn).

Comment: Well, I think it'll get difficult in a multi-site environment, to make some safe from SEO, and the other crawlable. At least it would require more development skills. If your personal website has nothing to do with the family one, I don't see any good reason to make them dependant on each other. Also, if you want to make some tests or anything on your personnal one, it shoudn't impact the family one.

Comment: Thanks for the htaccess.  I was aware of it, but after I read your answer, I did some more reading and it appears that it can provide "protection" based on folders (and their subfolders).  I wasn't aware of this--I thought it was for the entire website.  So, I think I understand your answer better--I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on your answer.  I think this is the answer, but I'll wait a bit before I check it.

Comment: Yes, basically access can protect a full domain, subdomain, subfolder and even URL pattern with some configuration. Although, the access login interface is pretty ugly. You can also protect WordPress with a custom login form. It can be done by code of course, but I think that a good combination of plugins can achieve it also. Still, access is the easiest/fastest way. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I like htaccess because it's at a lower level than wordpress (HTTP) and thus it should provide better protection.  If there was something similar at the TCP or IP level, I would prefer that.

Comment: You can do IP based whitelist from htaccess also (Google it),http level IP based. Or with fail2ban (IP level).

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called My private site which allows you to achieve what you are looking for: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-private-site/

A full detailed step by step (blogpost) tutorial on how to make your site private is published here:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-make-your-wordpress-blog-completely-private/